# Laravel custom delete method via pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a pivot table between `ingredients` and `images`. On the `Image` model I have a custom delete method which deletes the image from the s3 storage. The issue is that if I use `onDelete('cascade')` on the pivot table foreign keys the `delete()` method won't get fired. 
I tried a workaround but with no success.

My `Ingredient` model:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['ingredient_category_id', 'name', 'units', 'price'];

    ///////////////////
    // Relationships //
    ///////////////////
    public function images() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'ingredient_images')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /////////////
    // Methods //
    /////////////
    public function delete()
    {
        $this->images()->delete();
        $this->images()->detach();

        return parent::delete();
    }
}
```

My `Image` model:

```
class Image extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'path'];

    ///////////////////
    // Relationships //
    ///////////////////
    public function ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'ingredient_images')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /////////////
    // Methods //
    /////////////
    public function delete()
    {
        $this->ingredients()->detach();

        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($this->path);

        return parent::delete();
    }
}
```

My `pivot` table (`ingredient_images`):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ingredient_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('ingredient_id');
        $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredients');
        $table->unsignedInteger('image_id');
        $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I tried on the `Ingredient` model to have a custom `delete()` method which calls the `images()` delete method, the issue is that the method `delete()` from the `Image` model is not called (which is supposed to remove the image from the storage as well detach it from the pivot table)

When I try:

```
Ingredient::findOrFail($ids)->images()->delete()
Ingredient::findOrFail($ids)->delete()
```

I get:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the pivot table. In the pivot table there are two foreign keys. Your table will do nothing but throw an error when a related record is deleted since you did not give it a "referential action" to do something when this happens.

By adding the `onDelete()` you can give these referential actions. Depending on what you want you can give orders like: `cascade`, `set null`, `restrict`, `no action` and `set default`. More about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

In your case you want to use `cascade` which in this syntax basically means: "delete the record if the foreign key gets deleted".

Your migration will look like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ingredient_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('ingredient_id');
        $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredients')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('image_id');
        $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**First update after comment.**

Since `$ingredient->images()->delete()` will make use of the Eloquent builder to delete multiple records at once, the `Image@delete` will never be called.

Simple solution could be:

```
// Ingredient
public function delete() {
    foreach ($this->images as $image) {
        $image->delete();
    }

    return parent::delete();
}
```

This will ofcourse result in seperate queries to delete each image. Depending if you want to go for super mega hyperspeed this would not be your choice.

A suggestion would be using an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) (to keep your models clean) and an [event in combination with a queueable (optional) listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#queued-event-listeners).

Observer:

```
class IngredientObserver
{
    public function deleting(Ingredient $ingredient) {
        // Loop here
        foreach ($ingredient->images as $image) {
            Storage::disk('s3')->delete($image->path); // Or this can also be done in a seperate observer for Image to ensure the image is always deleted on AWS when deleting an image, that would be my choice.
            $image->delete();
        }

        // Or use an event

        $paths = $ingredient->images()->lists('path');

        $ingredient->images()->delete();

        event(new RemoveAwsImages($paths));
    }
}
```

Event:

```
class RemoveAwsImages
{
    public $paths;

    public __construct($paths) {
        $this->paths = $paths;
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RemoveAwsImagesListener implements ShouldQueue // Remember ShouldQueue is optional
{
    public function handle(RemoveAwsImages $event)
    {
        foreach ($event->paths as $paths) {
            Storage::disk('s3')->delete($path);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you do not have to add deletion methods inside you model and in combination with `onDelete('cascade')` you do not have to detach them.

I have not tested this code so there might be some small bugs.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of onDelete('cascade') but sadly this doesn't fire the delete() method I overridden in the Image model

Comment: @Alphonse not sure if this is true but it looks like you are calling `delete` directly on the `Eloquent\Builder` this means the `delete` method will never be fired. I will update my answer with a new possible solution.

Comment: And where should I register the observer? (sorry but i've never user one before) In the documentation they do something like: You may register an observer instance using the observe method:
User::observe(new UserObserver); Should I do: Ingredient::observer(new IngredientObserver)->findOrFail($ids)->delete()

Comment: As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers) tells, you can add the observer to your `AppServiceProvider` like `Ingredient::observer(IngredientObserver::class)` without `findOrFail` or `delete`.

Comment: Thank you, indeed this was the problem: $ingredient->images()->delete() will make use of the Eloquent builder to delete multiple records at once